# angularjs watch for change within group

Tags: angularjs

i have these array object

```
  $scope.filters = {
        1 : {
            name : 'Pattern',
            options : {
                1 : { name: 'Plain', selected: false },
                2 : { name: 'Self Design', selected: false },
                3 : { name: 'Check', selected: false },
                4 : { name: 'Stripe', selected: false },
                5 : { name: 'Print', selected: false },
                6 : { name: 'Others', selected: false }
            }
        },
        2 : {
            name : 'Colour',
            options : {
                1 : { name: 'White', selected: false },
                2 : { name: 'Blue', selected: false },
                3 : { name: 'Grey', selected: false },
                4 : { name: 'Pink', selected: false },
                5 : { name: 'Purple', selected: false },
                6 : { name: 'Black', selected: false },
                //7 : { name: 'Others', selected: false }                
            }
        },
        3 : {
            name : 'Material', 
            options : {
                1 : { name: 'Cotton', selected: false },
                2 : { name: 'Technicals', selected: false },
                3 : { name: 'CVC', selected: false },
                4 : { name: 'Cotton, Two Ply', selected: false }                
            }
        }
  }
```

how to get a group list of selected = true filters using $watch?

if possible i want the result stucture to be like this :

```
{
 Pattern : {
   1 : Plain,
   2 : Self Design
 },
Colour : {
   1: Blue
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var name ,options, selected = {};

for (var idx in $scope.filters) {
  name = $scope.filters[idx]['name'];
  options = $scope.filters[idx]['options'];
  for (var i in options) {
    if(options[i]['selected']) {
      selected[name] = selected[name] || {};
      selected[name][i] = options[i]['name'];
    }
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(selected,null,4));

/*

{
    "Pattern": {
        "1": "Plain",
        "2": "Self Design"
    },
    "Colour": {
        "2": "Blue"
    }
}

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XRuLMYNszGqBQT7kNPTp). Not the exact solution, but will give you a start.

I have used $watch (with objectEquality parameter) to get the changed object. You can then use underscore.js or pure javascript to filter out the selected items.